# Kendo Panning Issue

Tags: javascript, charts, kendo-ui

I used the Kendo pan and zoom demos for this and the zoom works fine, but when I try panning the chart just clears out all data.

I am using remote data for this

Here I call the remote data using a datasource:

```
    var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
        read: {
            url: "/Home/GetActivities",
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST"
        }
    },
    group: "Group",
    pageSize: viewSize,
    page: 0
});
```

The drag handle and other variables:

```
 //Maximum/Minimum number of visible items
var Min_Size = 5;
var Max_Size = 15;

//Minimum distance in px to start dragging
var Drag_Thr = 50;

//State variables
var viewStart = 0;
var viewSize = Min_Size;
var newStart;       

function onDrag(e) {
        var chart = e.sender;
        var ds = chart.dataSource;
        var delta = Math.round(e.originalEvent.x.initialDelta / Drag_Thr);

        if (delta != 0) {
            newStart = Math.max(0, viewStart - delta);
            newStart = Math.min(dataSource.length - viewSize, newStart);
            ds.query({
                skip: newStart,
                page: 0,
                pageSize: viewSize
            });
        }
    }

    function onDragEnd() {
        viewStart = newStart;
    }
```

And finally my chart:

```
$("#chart").kendoChart({
        theme: 'Metro',
        title: { text: 'Activities' },
        dataSource: dataSource,
        legend: { visible: true, position: "top" },
        series: [{ field: "Total", labels: { format: "{0}%", visible: true }, spacing: 0 }],
        valueAxis: { labels: { format: "{0}%" }, line: { visible: false }, max: 100, min: 0 },
        categoryAxis: { field: "Description", name: "Description", majorGridLines: { visible: false }, labels: { rotation: -90 } },
        tooltip: { visible: false },
        drag: onDrag,
        dragEnd: onDragEnd,
        zoom: onZoom
    });
```

I'm not sure what is wrong and causing the drag to clear out the chart data.

Thanks in advance for your help